# sh - Readonly array: bad variable name

Tags: scripts, sh

My script runs a program and checks the output with an expected one. Why is it not working?? (Prob an n00b mistake I'm making)

Console:

```
dan9er@A-Computer:~/Projects/Project$ ./Script.sh
./Script.sh: 13: readonly: FILENAMES[0]: bad variable name
```

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Copyright (c) 2017 Unattended Systems
# Some names & strings have been changed for confidentiality

#  ####### ### #       #######  #####
#  #        #  #       #       #
#  #####    #  #       #####    #####
#  #        #  #       #             #
#  #       ### ####### #######  #####

readonly FILENAMES[0]="0.file"
readonly FILENAMES[1]="1.file"
readonly FILENAMES[2]="2.file"
readonly FILENAMES[3]="3.file"
readonly FILENAMES[4]="4.file"
readonly FILENAMES[5]="5.file"
readonly FILENAMES[6]="6.file"
readonly FILENAMES[7]="7.file"
readonly FILENAMES[8]="8.file"
readonly FILENAMES[9]="9.file"
readonly FILENAMES[10]="10.file"
readonly FILENAMES[11]="11.file"
readonly FILENAMES[12]="12.file"
readonly FILENAMES[13]="13.file"
readonly FILENAMES[14]="14.file"
readonly FILENAMES[15]="15.file"
readonly FILENAMES[16]="16.file"
readonly FILENAMES[17]="17.file"
readonly FILENAMES[18]="18.file"
readonly FILENAMES[19]="19.file"
readonly FILENAMES[20]="20.file"
readonly FILENAMES[21]="21.file"

#  ####### #     # ######  #######  #####  ####### ####### ######
#  #        #   #  #     # #       #     #    #    #       #     #
#  #####      #    ######  #####   #          #    #####   #     #
#  #        #   #  #       #       #     #    #    #       #     #
#  ####### #     # #       #######  #####     #    ####### ######
#
#   #####  #     # ####### ######  #     # #######  #####
#  #     # #     #    #    #     # #     #    #    #
#  #     # #     #    #    ######  #     #    #     #####
#  #     # #     #    #    #       #     #    #          #
#   #####   #####     #    #        #####     #     #####

readonly EXPECTEDOUT[0]=$"Hello World!"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[1]="1"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[2]="2"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[3]="3"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[4]="4"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[5]="5"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[6]="6"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[7]="7"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[8]="8"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[9]="9"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[10]="10"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[11]="11"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[12]="12"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[13]="13"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[14]="14"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[15]="15"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[16]="16"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[17]="17"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[18]="18"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[19]="19"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[20]="20"
readonly EXPECTEDOUT[21]="21"

#  #        #####   #####  ###  #####
#  #       #     # #        #  #     #
#  #       #     # #  ####  #  #
#  #       #     # #     #  #  #     #
#  #######  #####   #####  ###  #####

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
do
    echo "Testing on file ${FILENAMES[$i]}"

    # Run program on file
    program ${FILENAMES[$i]} /tmp/tmp_out

    # If program's output CONTAINS the expected output for that file...
    if grep -q ${EXPECTEDOUT[$i]} /tmp/tmp_out.txt; then
        # ...record that a pass!
        echo -e "String \"${EXPECTEDOUT[$i]}\" found. Pass!"
        RESULTS[$i]=1
    else
        # ..otherwise, epic fail my dude
        echo -e "String \"${EXPECTEDOUT[$i]}\" not found. FAIL!"
        RESULTS[$i]=0
    fi
done

# Make a final list of results
PASSEDTESTS=0
for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
do
    if [[ ${RESULTS[$j]} == 1 ]]; then
        echo "${FILENAMES[$j]} passed"
        PASSEDTESTS=PASSEDTESTS+1
    else
        echo "${FILENAMES[$j]} failed"
    fi
done
echo "$PASSEDTESTS/22 files passed"
```

The file names do have underscores in them.

Comment: Did you tried with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: AFAIK `dash` doesn't support arrays at all (see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) ), and `bash` doesn't the support a `readonly` declaration for individual elements of an array. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: After you make the change recommended by @Redbob, copy-and-paste your code into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  Correct the errors that it shows.  If you still have problems or you don't understand shellcheck's error messages, then ask a question here.

Comment: You could use a temp file or heredoc structure instead of array. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404126/85039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver wrote in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962306#comment1538784_962306),

> `bash` doesn't the support a `readonly` declaration for individual elements of an array.

So once you've changed the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, as [waltinator suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/962311/301745), you'll need to change the array declarations:

```sh
FILENAMES[0]="0.file"
FILENAMES[1]="1.file"
...
readonly FILENAMES
```

Or you can shorten them by using array assignment (`=()`) and shell expansion (`{}`) syntax:

```sh
readonly FILENAMES=(
    {0..21}.file
    )

...

readonly EXPECTEDOUT=(
    $"Hello World!"
    {1..21}
    )
```

You can also shorten the loop declaration:

```sh
for i in {0..21}

...

for j in {0..21}
```

Answer (score 1):

By beginning your script with `#!/bin/sh`, you're telling the system to use the `dash` (POSIX features only) shell interpreter. See `man sh;man dash`. `dash` does not support shell arrays.

If you change the first line to `#!/bin/bash`, you'll get all the `bash` features, including arrays. See `man bash`.

Comment: that's correct plus as steeldriver commented above have the readonly at the end. so:

FILENAMES[0]="0.file"
FILENAMES[1]="1.file"
readonly FILENAMES